# Cocoa app to iOS (Objective-C) app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

Got a very open-ended question I'd like to pick peoples brains on. I have been given a project that was written originally as a Cocoa app for Mac OS X and now my client wishes to make it a native iOS application.

Does anyone have some best practices, theory or advice when porting an app over. When looking at the Cocoa code, it seems very similar to objective-c for iOS. I just want to make sure I don't fall into any traps in writing the iOS version.

Thanks for now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this several times. The most important part is getting your source application (OS X in this case) into a proper MVC architecture. Making sure your model layer is well-separated from your views will allow the model to come over easily. You will generally need to rewrite the UI from scratch, though I've occasionally had custom Core Graphics views that could be brought over with minimal effort (just by flipping the coordinate system). But generally plan to rewrite the UI entirely. In most cases you will require a new approach to user experience anyway.

That said, all your data model, networking, processing, etc. can easily be ported as long as you make sure it is all in Foundation, not AppKit, classes.

Comment: Awesome thank you for the insight! Good to know it has been done before. As for making sure classes are all in Foundation and not AppKit...do you know of any good ways to detect this and change them to the right Foundation classes?

Comment: Take the `#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>` or `#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>` out of your pch file, and then make sure that your model classes compile with just `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`. Foundation is the same on both platforms, but Cocoa and AppKit are different.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a pencil and index cards or paper, and start figuring out what features you need to do and what UI elements are needed. With that get a big table and play around with the cards - do you need one Nav Controller or a tabBarController with Nav controllers in it.

Once you have everything covered, wire the cards up, say left to right, or tape them to something and start connecting things. Once you have it 80% right you can start coding.

There is no magic tool that I know - the best one is probably between your ears! But don't start coding til you figured out how it all works.